# How to stop listening in a Spring Kafka consumer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use `Spring for Apache Kafka`. I'd like to stop listening to my topic and wait to escape OOM. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use the pause() and resume() methods of the consumer for the same.

Comment: Diagnose the root cause of OOM, instead of getting distracted to pause() / resume().  OOM likely due to incorrect SSL, partition mismatch etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void stopConsumer(final String topic) {    
     ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container 
         = consumersMap.get(topic);
     container.stop();    
 }
```

Comment: What is `consumersMap`?

Answer (score 1):

With Spring boot and Spring Cloud, there is a way to stop a particular consumer using actuators.

Kafka Streams binder of Spring Cloud  allows us to start or stop a consumer or function binding associated with it.

Add `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include =  bindings` in application.properties ( or yaml formatted property in application.yml)

A GET call to `http://localhost:9009/actuator/bindings` would expose all the bindings.

A POST call to `http://localhost:9009/actuator/bindings/{name}` can start or stop the binding.

Sample cURL to Stop a consumer :
`curl -d '{"state":"STOPPED"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/actuator/bindings/consumer-in-0`

Sample cURL to Start a consumer :
`curl -d '{"state":"STARTED"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/actuator/bindings/consumer-in-0`

Visit [Spring Cloud Stream Binder Documentation](https://%5Bhttps://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_binding_visualization_and_control_in_kafka_streams_binder%5D) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka provides an option to pause() and resume() the consumption from a topic. You can use these methods by implementing a wait in between to revive from the memory issue.

Reference: https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: The question was about Spring Kafka, not plain Kafka.